# How to set a variable to utilize querySelectorAll to reference all elements selected by the selector [data-clue-A=clue]

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I am trying to set wordLetters to reference all elements selected by the CSS selector [data-clue-A=clue] where clue is the value of data-clue-a for the object currentLetter.
I have tried:

wordLetters = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-clue-A = 'currentLetter.dataset.clueA']');

but it gives me error.

Comment: Huh? Can you add examples to make it clear what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the string isn't in the right form for concatenation.

Try this:

```
wordLetters = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-clue-A=' + currentLetter.dataset.clueA + ']');
```